# Regarding Service Account on Google Play Store

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-play-services, google-developer-tools

I have an app on the Google Play store , and I  have  associated service account(On Google Developer console) with Google Play.I want to access the Google Play Developer API with associated service account in PHP. But I do not have the associated service account key (the Json file).

Correct me if I am wrong , we are suppose to download the key json file when we create the service account at Google Developer Console.If I have lost it or don't have it then can i re-download the same ?

If I can't re-download it then can I create a new one with my existing service account without impacting my existing system on the Google Play Store ?

I am new to this , so kindly bear me ignorance .

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) on how to mange service account keys. If you delete a key, your application will no longer be able to access Cloud Platform resources using that key. A security best practice is to rotate your service account keys regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the project and service account can be created through the Play Console, under the hood it is just another project in the [API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/).

[All the docs are here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).

But here's a quick guide:

- Once you are on the console, go to the IAM and admin page
- On the side menu choose service accounts
- find your service account
- there is a vertical 3 dot menu at the end of the row, beyond the options column
- choose "create private key". This will mean any scripts you already have will need the new key, but everything else should just keep working